# SQL query for aggreating a related object

Tags: php, mysql, one-to-one

I have two tables as posts and comments. Each row in comments table has id of the post which it belong to. How can I select, for example, most commented ten posts?

Comment: this query is very easy. Have you tried something? don't ask to code for you, this is very basic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(c.id) tot
FROM posts p INNER JOIN comments c
ON p.id = c.post_id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY tot DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @diEcho: oh, my fault... I had a bad day and I didn't notice this... yes, you're absolutely right, `LIMIT` goes to the end!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

you can use group by for this
some query like

```
SELECT posts, count(comment) as total 
from comments group by (post) order by total;
```

Comment: I think you're missing relation between tables and you're selecting comments, not most commented posts. Finally you're not getting top ten.